# Interpolate price/IV for strike and expiry between market given expiry dates and strikes

Tags: c++, quantlib

I have looked "everywhere" but I cannot find one. Is there an **example** of how to use c++ Quantlib on how to interpolate for options prices with synthetic strikes/expiry dates?

So for example, if "today" is February 6, 2017, and I get mass quote of the INTC  option chain for the expiry's of February 17 2017, March 17 2017, April 14 2017 (etc), and for the sake of argument say the strikes in the mass quote are in $5 wide increments from 15 to 45, and I compute the IV surface for that mass quote for the market given expiry dates/strikes/prices (using some model), **how do interpolate for a __synthetic__ expiry date and/or strike, say I want the IV and price for the "April 5, 2017, 39.33 strike call" option?**

I see that QL support these interpolation methods, but I am unsure which to use or how to set up the problem to run the solver(s).

```
LinearInterpolation (1-D)
LogLinearInterpolation and LogCubicInterpolation (1-D)
BackwardFlatInterpolation (1-D)
ConvexMonotone (1-D)
CubicInterpolation (1-D)
ForwardFlatInterpolation (1-D)
SABRInterpolation (1-D)
BilinearInterpolation (2-D)
BicubicSpline (2-D)
```

[I probably don't want to use weekly's to interpolate in between. Probably only the monthly and quarterly expiration since I believe those prices especially the further out the expiry is.]

This is a similar problem as bootstraping a yield curve, except we are bootstraping on the dimension of strike/tenor between known values on the vol surface, to some given granularity. It is also interesting that we can see new values of `NPV` changes to an option by simulating changes the underlying value with no extra work [since the market data are stored in Quote instances and thus can notify the option when any of the parameters changes] and holding everything else constant. That the library does not support the same kind of "simulation" by turning the dial on strikes/tenor seems an omission. It is also an inverse problem, using different dimensions.

I need both American and European with/without dividends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a Black volatility surface and let it interpolate.

At this time, the only class you have available to do this is the `BlackVarianceSurface` class.  Its constructor takes a vector of exercise dates, a vector of strikes, and a matrix of corresponding volatilities.  The matrix must be full, so you'll need to quote a volatility for each combination of exercise and strike. By default, it uses bilinear interpolation on variances; the method can be changed by calling

```
volSurface.setInterpolation<Bicubic>();
```

after construction.

Once you have built the surface, you can use it to get volatilities and prices.  To get the volatility, ask the surface:

```
Volatility v = volSurface.blackVol(exerciseDate, strike);
```

will interpolate on the exercise date and strike and return the volatility.  To get the price, pass the whole surface to an instance of a Black-Scholes process, pass the process to an engine and use the latter to price the option; the engine will pick the correct volatility for the given exercise and strike.